# Can we remove "on behalf of" from the "from address" on Messaging.sendEmail()?

Tags: apex, administration

I changed the from email address by setting the OrgWideAddress; but still the email's from address says

```
noreply@salesforce.com on behalf of testEmail@test.com
```

Can it be changed to a regular email name without "on behalf of"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [salesforce knowledge article](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000167022&language=en_US) that covers this.
Go to Setup > Administration Setup > Email Administration > Deliverability
Under the email security compliance section, turn off the SenderID compliance checkbox, and now email vendor / clients will not include the "Send on behalf of".

Please keep in mind, by enable to comply with Sender ID email protocols. This declares salesforce.com emails as coming from an authorized IP address.

An alternative as well is to enable Email Relaying. What is Email Relaying? 
Email relaying is using an email server to send email that did not originate on the email server. Companies set up email relaying to:

- Route all email through their own email servers to avoid the appearance of email spoofing by Salesforce. Email spoofing is the forging of email headers to make messages appear as if they came from someone other than the original sender.
- Store copies of all email as required by government regulations in various industries.
- Apply existing content filters that scan messages for data and content that is not approved to be sent out through company email.
- Run outbound email through antivirus software before sending it to customers.
- Append data such as company-wide disclaimers at the bottom of email messages.

You can set up email relaying for Salesforce-generated email by configuring Salesforce to automatically route email through your company's Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) server.

For more information on how to setup [Email Relay Please Click Me](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_relay.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Can you edit this answer and provide the actual solution to the problem rather than linking to the SFDC ideas page? It would also be nice if you were to describe the side-effects of disabling "Sender Id Compliance" and maybe describe using Email Relaying as an alternate solution...

Comment: Is this better Mark? Please let me know what changes you would like.

Comment: @DoubleA much better! Thanks for responding. There's always the chance of the idea going away in the future (and now this post is still helpful if it does), and besides linking to an idea can be confusing as the default behavior is to ask the user to vote for if it impacts them.

Comment: @ca_peterson No problem. Completely understandable.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the best deliverability without "on behalf", you will have to use an smtp relay.  This can be tricky to set up. Check www.salesforcesmtp.com for a solution. It can also rewrite sender email addresses in case you have partner users sending emails from the platform with a different domain.