# Remove on behalf of user@companydomain.com from emails (send all emails from noreply@salesforce.com)

Tags: email, administration, deliverability

I am facing an issue regarding emails from salesforce.

Salesforce emails are being sent as:

- noreply@salesforce.com on behalf of user1@companydomain.com

Since the user that receives the emails shares the same domain as the sender, and the email is interpreted as external, all emails are automatically blocked.

I am aware I can hide the noreply@salesforce.com part of the from by unselecting the 'Enable Sender ID compliance' setting.

But, I want to send all emails from salesforce like this:

- noreply@salesforce.com

removing the on "behalf of user1@companydomain.com".

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Hello Joao, have you seen this [response](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/92549/45578) by any chance? I also suggest you include the source of emails (apex, workflow, etc.).

Comment: Hi @JefersonChaves. That solution worked perfectly. I should have researched better. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.